# How does pandas perform row and column transposition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, wifi, data-analysis

I am processing data with pandas, the data source is the signal strength of a set of wifi and the label of this set of data. I saved them to sqlite and then read them with pandas. As shown in Figure 1, I want to convert them into the form of Figure 2. How can I do this? The first column in Figure 1 is time. Grouped by time, mac is the column, rssi is the value corresponding to the mac column, and label corresponds to the time.
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pSWu.png)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7cXE.png)

Comment: You can use `import pandas as pd`, then `pd.DataFrame(your data frame).transpose()`

Comment: how can i determine the param?

Comment: first, you need to select the columns. For example: `new_df = df[['mac','rssi']]`. Then transpose them, `new_df.transpose()`

Comment: how can i group by time If i transpose df['mac','rssi']?

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you've tried so far?